# .NET does not deserialize correctly DateTime values in DataSet serialized to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datetime, serialization

I am writing a program that serializes a DataSet into a XML file, then the same program deserializes it in another computer to save it into a database. For serialization/deserialization I use the DataSet ReadXml/WriteXml methods.

The problem is that .NET isn´t deserializing DateTime values correctly. When I try to deserialize a DateTime value, instead of getting a DateTime, I get a string like "2018-01-15T00:00:00-03:00" instead. Then when I try to save that date in a database I get a cast error.

How can I deserialize a DateTime value properly?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32102550/1132334, probably culture.

Comment: Setting XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema when writing the XML fixed the issue, but I really don´t want to use a schema at all, because the columns on the DataSet may vary, so I don´t want to get any schema errors.